# How to connect between android (server) and Android (client) using wifi

Tags: android

i'm building app chat wifi that have the database in the device
so my question is  how to **connect** between android (**server**) and Android (**client**) using **wifi**

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good tutorial for doing what you want:

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/

EDIT: For a good read on how to read and write from an SQLite Database, have a look at this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

I'm not going to post any code, since the link supplies you with this.

Also have a look at the official guides for data storage here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: thx this is a good tutorial but i'm looking for receive and read msg from database

Comment: Then you should definately re-phrase your question, because that's not what it states.

Comment: that was good but i had create my database end i can read and write from it but in the same device (server)
now i want to connect to this database from another device (client)
thanx

Comment: I've answered all your questions as the question is right now. I think you should accept the answer and open another question where you re-phrase what it is that you want to accomplish, together with a description of what you have tried as well. Drawing a diagram could help other people to understand your problem better.

Comment: great @Darwind,... i saw that example. From the server side it implemented the Thread (runnable) and listening to specific socket... and to the client side it implemented the Thread (runnable) also to connect to the IP of the Server previously. But My question is, is it possible if the Server Device (the first device) act both role? Server act as a Server + Client in the same device? I mean, maybe to implement the Two Threads on the android server.

Comment: @gumuruh the short answer is "yes" ;-) I'd recommend you create a new question instead, as answering your question here would clutter the original question.